# Loss Of Significance $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$

Tags: numerical-methods

Let  $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$  and $x=0.12345\cdot 10^5$ if the numbers are stored in decimal mantissa with $6$ significant digits we will get

$$f(0.12345\cdot 10^5)=\sqrt{0.12346\cdot 10^5}-\sqrt{0.12345\cdot 10^5}=\\=0.111113\cdot 10^3-0.111108\cdot 10^3=0.5\cdot 10^{-2}$$

So the relative error is $$\frac{0.5\cdot 10^{-3}}{0.5\cdot 10^{-2}}=10\%$$

How did we get to this relative error? shouldn't it be $$\delta=\frac{\mid f(x_1)-f(x_2)\mid}{\mid f(x_1)\mid}$$

Where $f(x^1)$ is the exact number and $f(x_2)$ is the approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you get is $0.5\cdot 10^{-2}$. The exact answer is closer to $0.45\cdot10^{-2}$. Thus the relative error is
$$
\frac{|0.45\cdot 10^{-2}-0.5\cdot10^{-2}|}{|0.45\cdot 10^{-2}|}\\=\frac{0.5\cdot10^{-3}}{0.45\cdot10^{-2}}=11\%
$$